# prove$\dfrac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial u\partial v}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

function $z=f\left( x,y\right)$,
$\begin{cases}x=u+v\\ y=uv\end{cases}$

I want to prove this. ↓↓
$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial u\partial v}= \dfrac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial x^{2}}+x\dfrac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial x\partial y}+y\dfrac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial y^{2}}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}\end{aligned}$

I think

$\begin{aligned}\dfrac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial u\partial v}=\dfrac{\partial }{\partial u}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial v} =\dfrac{\partial }{\partial u} \left( \dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial y}u\right) \end{aligned}$

I don't know what to do next.
Please tell me.

Comment: Your use of `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}` is weird, and not necessary (it also didn't compile in your title). You probably just want to use `$$...$$`, which puts everything on its own line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the following result:-

If $f=f(x,y)$ where $x=x(s,t)$ and $y=y(s,t)$ then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}$$
Applying these results repeatedly to the given expression,
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial v} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}u$$
$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)+\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(u\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)$$
$$=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+u\frac{\partial}{\partial u}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial ^2z}{\partial y \partial x}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+u\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+u\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\left(\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\right)\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
$$=\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y \partial x}v+u\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x \partial y}+uv\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
and finally we get
$$\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial u \partial v}=\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial x^2}+x\frac{\partial ^2 z}{\partial y \partial x}+y\frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial y^2}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$$
where it is assumed that $f$ is continuous for the equality of mixed partial derivatives.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understood.